# HTTP ETags and HTTP Redirects

Tags: http, go, etag

I have a webserver that issues the `ETag` header on responses and checks the `If-None-Match` header from the client, if present. The client in this case, is not a web browser but an extension of go's builtin `net/http` `http.Client` type.

Here is my code

```
package util

import "net/http"
import "net/url"

type HttpClient struct {
    http.Client
    etags map[url.URL]string
}

func (hc *HttpClient) Do(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    const ETAG_SERVER_HEADER = "ETag"
    const ETAG_CLIENT_HEADER = "If-None-Match"

    //Do not attempt to use ETags on non-GET requests
    if req.Method != "GET" {
        return hc.Client.Do(req)
    }

    //Check for an existing etag
    etag, ok := hc.etags[*req.URL]
    if ok { //If an ETag is present, send it along
        if req.Header == nil {
            req.Header = http.Header{}
        }
        req.Header.Add(ETAG_CLIENT_HEADER, etag)
    }

    //Do the response
    response, err := hc.Client.Do(req)
    //If the response is ok
    if err == nil {

        if hc.etags == nil {
            hc.etags = make(map[url.URL]string)
        }

        //Check for an ETAG from the server, store it if present
        etag = response.Header.Get(ETAG_SERVER_HEADER)
        if len(etag) != 0 {
            hc.etags[*req.URL] = etag
        }
    }

    return response, err
}
```

It is working without issue as of present.

I am only storing and sending the ETag for `GET` requests. While it is valid to send them for other requests, it is not in my use case as of current so I'm not bothering with it. The ETags are stored by mapping the `url.URL` object to a string.

My question is this. I request "http://foo.com/bar.html". The server redirects me using `302 Found` and the `Location` header to "http://foo.com/qux.html". I then request "http://foo.com/qux.html" and get a `200 OK` along with an `ETag` header.

With what URL do I associate the `ETag` header from the last response?

Could the `302 Found` itself include an `ETag` header?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An [ETag](http://httpwg.github.io/specs/rfc7232.html#header.etag) is associated with the "selected representation" of the current request. The selected representation for a [302 Found](http://httpwg.github.io/specs/rfc7231.html#status.302) response "usually contains a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the different URI(s)." Therefore, if a 302 response contains an ETag, the ETag is associated with that hypertext.

However, if you include an If-None-Match (or other precondition) in a request to a resource that responds with a redirect, the server will ignore the precondition. According to [Section 5 of RFC 7232](http://httpwg.github.io/specs/rfc7232.html#evaluation) (my emphasis):

> A server MUST ignore all received preconditions if its response to the same request without those conditions would have been a status code other than a 2xx (Successful) or 412 (Precondition Failed). In other words, **redirects and failures take precedence over the evaluation of preconditions** in conditional requests.

Thus, while a 302 response can contain an ETag, it is not useful because the server may not use it in further requests to that resource.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in [/src/pkg/net/http/client.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/client.go#L266) on line 266 the request-response cycle will continue until either or:

- The `http.Client`'s redirect checker (`CheckRedirect` field) returns an error
- The response received is not a redirect (according to [shouldRedirectGet](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/client.go#L190))

During the cycle , previous responses will be discarded and the headers the response that `client.Do` returns are those of the last response.

This means that you should associate the `ETag` with `qux.html` in your example.

> Could the 302 Found itself include an ETag header?

Yes it could but since it's a redirect, the client will follow it and acquire a new set of response headers from the target URL.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The fact that I am using Go is incidental to the question. The redirect behavior of `http.Client` doesn't change the meaning of the RFC that dictates ETags.

Comment: You should probably reformulate your question to mention that RFC and that you want to conform to it.